# Proof for a Markov process example (using measure theory)

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Consider the probability space $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}),\delta_x)$ for a given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure) and define the process $X_t(\omega)=\omega - t$, for $t\geq 0$.

How does one prove that $X_t$ is a Markov process with respect to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t = B(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Since $\sigma(X_t)=\mathbb B(\mathbb R)$, the Markov property is trivial.

Comment: Would you mind giving a bit of detail? I am unable to see why.

Comment: Do you know what Markov property is?

Comment: The way it has been presented to us is the following: for all $t$, $\mathcal{F}_t$ and the $\sigma(X_s, s\geq t)$ must be independent conditioned by $X_t$.

Comment: Ok, so from that, what is $\mathcal F_t$ in our context?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_t = B(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo You might rather have asked to show that $\sigma(X_s;s\geqslant t)=\sigma(X_t)$.

Comment: @k123 Sure about the probability being $\delta_x$? This trivializes things a tad too much, if you ask me.